# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I create a simple Web application but when I want to run it I got this message in "Tools Output":

> Could not find a file named"pubspec.yaml"in"/home/reza/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.10.0+2".

How can I fix this problem?

I use Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit and Dart Editor 1.7.2

Comment: In my case, the reason for this problem was that I used to pull the packges using `flutter pub get`, but I ran build_runner with `dart run build_runner ...`. But `flutter` and `dart` use different working directories.

So be sure to run build_runner with the same command as the one you pulled the packages with.

Comment: The above was my problem too! Why not make an answer out of that?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This has happened to me several times:

What's ultimately solved things for me (OS X) is deleting pub's cache:

`sudo rm -Rf /Users/<username>/.pub-cache`

Also, delete the packages directory in your project's root:

`sudo rm -Rf .packages`

Then `pub get` again in your project(s), but *make sure* that you are *not* operating as root (a `whoami` will tell you, and an `exit` will get you out of there).

Comment: Thank you for this, had me stuffing around for half hour before I tried SO. Your solution worked. My packages folder was in `.packages` so I issued `sudo rm -Rf .packages` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting 
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in ".pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/devtools...". 
And after remove .pub-cache + pub get now is working fine.

Comment: On windows, I deleted the pubspec.lock file, after that I wrote to console flutter clean and flutter pub get. It works like this on windows

Comment: I have this error with the first comand: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 64):

I was facing a similar issue when running even a simple `dart run`:

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in '/Users/<username>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animated_widgets-1.1.0'
```

So I managed to fix it by these steps:

- `sudo rm -Rf /Users/<username>/.pub-cache`.
- `flutter clean` in the current project folder.
- **MOST IMPORTANT** run `dart pub get`
- `flutter pub get`

And it finally worked

Comment: Thank you, `dart pub get` did it for me 

Comment: Didn't work, still get error: Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Library/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_info_plus-3.1.1".

Comment: `dart pub get` was the issue for me as well

Comment: **Deleting the folder is important** 
I tried starting from step 2, it didn't work. 
You have to delete `/Users/<username>/.pub-cache` first

Comment: Thanks for highlighting `dart pub get`, that what I was missing. Apparently it depends on the package that causing the error, i.e. for some cases, `flutter pub get` do the trick but some times you also need to do `dart pub get`

Answer (score 22):

run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 19):

I looks like your pub cache is corrupted. You can try to run `pub cache repair` from the command line but I think that this is still not working when the `pubspec.yaml` file is missing (there was an open issue about this - found it: http://dartbug.com/21418). Please try to delete the folder `/home/reza/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.10.0+2` and then run `pub get` from within your project directory or from DartEditor.

Comment: i tried to delete that folder but when i type "ls" in terminal in reza directory there is no folder with ".pubcache" name .

Comment: What about `.pub-cache`?

Comment: there is no .pub-cache folder too

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried to run `pub get` or `pub upgrade` in your projects directory?

Comment: Very weird. I think you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new. There are some known issues related to `.pub-cache` but I haven't seen anything like this yet.

Comment: My dart is working well, and i can find a .pub-cache folder at my root

Answer (score 15):

this will also occur if your pubspec.yaml file reffers to some other pubspec file. Try removing paths from the pubspec.yaml and replace with a version instead, like this.

```
flutter_local_notifications:
    path: ../
```

**To This**

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1+1
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution works on the newer versions of flutter. If you can not find your pub cache, you will find it here:

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Pub`

Delete the `Cache` folder
Run `pub cache repair`
Run `flutter pub get`

Comment: In my case, I just needed to delete the cache folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it happened after I was update flutter version.

cd to the current project folder.

```
 flutter clean
 flutter pub get
```

finally `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` 
It's Worked~

Answer (score 4):

For windows, cleaning the pub cache worked for me, I am also using Flutter version manager

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

then use

```
flutter pub get
```

just add `fvm` at the start if you're also using it

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for David's answer which helped me to find and delete pub cache directory in my mac.

```
sudo rm -Rf /Users/<user-name>/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache
```

There's a change in the path mentioned by David.

Answer (score 3):

### Update #1: Flutter 3.0.1

Had a very similar error message recently after running `flutter doctor` :

```
Building flutter tool...
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/test-1.20.2".
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/test-1.20.2".
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (8 tries left)
^CError: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (7 tries left)
```

Resolved by:

1. Login as authorized user
2. Add group permission to the folder tree
   using `sudo chmod -R g+rwx /opt/flutter`

> Note - Problem reappeared after upgrading Flutter to 3.0. This seems to confirm that the default flutter permissions did not respect my group ownership for all new files. Following the fix to the group permissions, flutter was able to complete my upgrade to 3.0.1.

### Original Answer:

> Note: My initial error was pointing to this particular folder.

```
/opt/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine
```

1. I `touched` the pubspec.yaml file and then did a `cat` on the file to
   confirm that it existed. The file was there with all the yaml type
   info.
2. Next I checked the permissions (using `ls -ll`) and noticed that my *group* did not
   have the correct permissions set to the pubspec.yaml file in the
   folder. (my user-account doesn't own the folder but my group has access)
3. After logging in as the authorized user account; I changed the group permissions
   using `sudo chmod -R g+rwx /opt/flutter/bin` and then verified my permissions on the files in the target folder.
4. Ran `flutter pub get` from the project folder with no more trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution would be to delete your .pub-cache folder and then pub get again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. to resolve the problem I tried many ways suggested on the internet, but nothing worked. then I went to the path
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache
and deleted "Cache" folder and after deleting this folder I restarted IDE and run the "pub get" command and it solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

> FileSystemException(path=/Users/username/Documents/development/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/_embedder.yaml; message=Cannot open file)
> [SEVERE] mobx_codegen:mobx_generator on lib/view/main/squad/viewmodel/view_model.dart (cached):

1. `sudo chmod -R g+rwx /Users/<username>/Documents/development/flutter`
2. `rm -rf cache`
3. `sudo rm -Rf .packages`
4. `flutter clean`
5. `flutter pub get`
6. finaly `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.

```
sudo rm -Rf /Users/username/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache
```

take care, the path must be right!

Answer (score 2):

For **Windows** user

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache
```

**Delete this Cache folder**

Then, go to project, run

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the cache isn't necessary, the issue means the pkg couldn't be found in the cache.. simply install/activate the pkg to make it globally accessible using;

`dart pub global activate package_name`

In my case, Flutterfire was failing to run.

Answer (score 2):

1. `rm pubspec.lock`(MacOS)/`del pubspec.lock`(Win)
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub cache clean`
4. `flutter pub get`

This should do the work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

After trying many solutions, I found one that works for me.

1. Delete all libraries from flutter->.pub-cache->hosted->pub.dartlang.org
2. And run the given below commands in terminal,

> ```
> flutter clean
> flutter pub get
> ```

**Note: Run above commands in terminal not from Tools->flutter->flutter clean / flutter pub get**

Answer (score 0):

For me neither worked deleting .pub-cache or packages from project root. The solution was removing the directories from ~/.pub-cache/git seperately.

In my case I have had 6 packages hosted on git so I have had to remove each package and call `flutter pub get` every time for all the 6 packages.
After doing that, everything seems working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete or repair the entire cache (takes a long time)

You can simply delete the problematic package, in this specific case:
`/home/reza/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.10.0+2"`

But make sure to copy the value from your error message.

Then run:
`flutter pub get` or `pub get`

Answer (score 0):

1.**Just delete flutter from root folder like "C:/src/flutter".**

2.**Download from here https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows**

3.**Set the path inside user variables under  Edit environment variables.**

4.**Then just reset the path on android studio**....

after that the problem will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some error in pubspec.yaml file, after fixing the error in pubspec.yaml the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

On MacOs I had to run:

sudo rm -Rf /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.8.1/flutter/.pub-cache

Prior to this I tried most of the above but was still getting the same error, 'cannot find a .yaml' file

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using these steps in MacOS:

1. First running Flutter clean
2. Running "sudo rm -Rf packages" in terminal
3. Going to correct package directory where "pubspec.yaml" file is located
4. Running "flutter pub get" in terminal
5. Checking that "builder_runner" package is in "pubspec.yaml" file.
6. Running "flutter packages pub run build_runner build" in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Put your flutter sdk path before your original command,
remove the flutter before the original command

```
> D:\sdks\flutter3.3.10\bin\flutter.bat pub run
```

then simply press enter

Answer (score 0):

i solved this error, by removing local reference path which were not exist in  `path: ../`.
i were using

```
 flutter_overlay_window:
        path: ../
```

replace above to this below code

```
flutter_overlay_window: ^0.10.5
```

`flutter_overlay_window` this can be any package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error appeared after forking a package and trying to reference my fork. Turned out that

```dart
package:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/company/package.git
    ref: master
```

tried to search for a `pubspec.yaml` in the root of the repo which doesn't exist. So I had to tell my pubspec where to look.

```dart
package:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/company/package.git
    ref: master
    path: subfolder
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named
"pubspec.yaml" in
"/Users/osx/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
percent_indicator-3.0.1".)

Solution

The simple solution would be to delete your /osx/flutter/.pub-cache folder and then flutter pub get.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, could be yours too, I am linux(debian) user, I've a problem like this :

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.7.1".
pub finished with exit code 66
```

and i fix it, with following comands:

```
sudo rm -Rf /opt/flutter/.pub-cache
sudo rm -Rf packages
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error and tried to resolve it by going to the location displayed in the debug console, deleting the packages directories displayed there, and then running pug get

Comment: ... and the result of that attempt was ....?