# Error: No pubspec.yaml file found when running flutter for the first time

Tags: flutter

I tried to follow `Get Stated` here https://flutter.io/setup-windows/

And got

```
>flutter run
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.
```

How to fix?

Comment: You need to run that command in a folder containing a `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: ... which you could create by `flutter create somefolder` - `flutter help create` for more details. Then `cd` to somefolder and `flutter run` there. There are a few IDEs that will automate this for you: Visual Studio Code, IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio.

Comment: @RémiRousselet why isn't it said in the doc!?

Comment: The doc mention it. https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58303167/11675817

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Download](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/beta/windows/flutter_windows_v0.3.2-beta.zip) the zip file (Assuming you have already done this)
- Extract this zip to a safe place say "E://flutter/"
- Open CMD and goto your workspace folder where to usually create your projects.
- Run command `flutter create <project_name>`
- `cd <project_name>`
- Run command `flutter run`

Alternatively, you can always use a good IDE like [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows) or Android Studio which will automate such configs like @Rechard said.

Answer (score 12):

You are not in the current working directory. Change the directory to your project directory and then run >>flutter run so that it could find pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run any command in terminal and getting error of pubspec.ymal not found then Close that session of terminal that you are currently using and open a new one...

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced with this problem recently. I researched it a little bit and actually there is no particular solution for that problem.

But the way I solved it was:

1) Forget about the file which gives the error.

2) Create a new one like how you've created before.

3) After that call the **flutter run** thing again. It should work as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me i just went to the terminal, cd to the directory where you want to get the dependencies and just run 'flutter pub get'.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open new session.