# FLUTTER: Error: No pubspec.yaml file found

Tags: flutter

```
mac@MACs-MacBook-Air ChatApp % flutter pub get
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
mac@MACs-MacBook-Air ChatApp % flutter upgrade
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b1395592de (5 days ago) • 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
Engine • revision 2dce47073a
Tools • Dart 2.12.2
mac@MACs-MacBook-Air ChatApp % flutter clean
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
mac@MACs-MacBook-Air ChatApp %
```

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375407/error-no-pubspec-yaml-file-found-when-running-flutter-for-the-first-time

Answer (score 1):

Execute the relevant commands in your project root directory. If you accidentally delete pubspec.yaml, create a new one.