# No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Parameter format not correct

> √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...

I got this type of massage when I run the project and after no further process is done

Answer (score 0):

Extract this zip to a safe place say "E://flutter/"

Open CMD and goto your workspace folder where to usually create your projects.

Run command flutter create <project_name>

cd <project_name>

Run command flutter run

answer on this question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375407/error-no-pubspec-yaml-file-found-when-running-flutter-for-the-first-time)