# Flutter codes not executing on android emulator

Tags: java, android, flutter

```
C:\Users\TomiwaPC>flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.30], locale en-NG)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc2)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    [√] Connected device (2 available)
    
    • No issues found!
```

I have upgraded my flutter. Done everything I could
No error was reported.
Please I would like to know how i can resolve this issue.

Please find below the links to screenshots  for some clarification:

[flutter and emulator screenshots][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz0Aq.png

[android sdk screenshots][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS3og.png

[project structure screenshots][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU25L.png

I would be glad if you can assist with your experience.
Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that in the emulator is connected? I use android studio and there is a dropdown menu to select an emulator.
Here's what my one looks like, it's at the top toolbar section:

Comment: I have done that. Still experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `"flutter pub get"` on the terminal for fetching dependencies before running the project?

Comment: C:\Users\TomiwaPC>flutter pub get
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.                                                      I was getting Error: No pubspec.yaml file found after running flutter pub get. Please what can I do

Comment: Refer     [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786432/how-do-i-fix-no-pubspec-yaml-file-found-in-flutter#:~:text=Make%20sure%20you%20have%20set,flutter%20run%22%20from%20that%20folder)

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter devices` and ensure your device is listed, then run `flutter run` in your project directory.

Comment: C:\Users\TomiwaPC>flutter devices
1 connected device:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114

C:\Users\TomiwaPC>flutter run
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.