# How can I solve this error? "package_config.json does not exist. Did you run this command from the same directory as your pubspec.yaml file?"

Tags: flutter, dart

I encountered this error after update targetSdk 31 to 33. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073233/error-package-config-json-does-not-exist-when-running-the-project) question but I could not solve it. How can I solve this error?

```
/Users/xxx/xxx/.dart_tool/package_config.json does not exist.
Did you run this command from the same directory as your pubspec.yaml file?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "package\_config.json does not exist" when running the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073233/error-package-config-json-does-not-exist-when-running-the-project)

Comment: Yes, this is the same question but I couldn't solve this problem even though I tried the solution.