# why does flutter show me this error and how can i solve it?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk

Good morning, I have a problem with the flutter app am using vscode, and after resolving the configuration's problems I have this problem and I couldn't solve it can you please help me with this?

when I run "flutter pub get" it shows me this message:

> Because every version of flutter_test from SDK depends on meta 1.3.0
> and active_ecommerce_flutter depends on meta ^1.4.0, flutter_test from
> SDK is forbidden. So, because active_ecommerce_flutter depends on
> flutter_test any from SDK, version solving failed. Running "flutter
> pub get" in ACT...                                      pub get failed
> (1; So, because active_ecommerce_flutter depends on flutter_test any
> from SDK, version solving failed.)

thank you for your collaboration.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your pubspec.yaml? It is related to some dependency issues.

Answer (score 9):

This problem is because your flutter version is using `meta 1.3.0`and your active_ecommerce_flutter is using `meta 1.4.0` causing a conflict.

**Solution 1:**

Upgrade your flutter version by typing `flutter upgrade` in the terminal.

However, at the point of time of writing this answer, the latest stable version of flutter is still using `meta 1.3.0`.
Thus, you will need to upgrade from a different channel than "stable", like (beta, dev, or master).

example:

```
 flutter channel dev
 flutter upgrade
```

**Solution 2:**

Try downgrading your `active_ecommerce_flutter` step by step till reaching a compatible version.

**Solution 3: (Recommended)**

Just add this line in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependency_overrides:
  meta: ^1.3.0
```

This will force using `meta: ^1.3.0`

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I thought I was crazy, or my app was broken, I spent ages on  this.

FYI - Stable release 2.5.0 now uses meta 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I think This is an SDK issue which you are using,

Upgrade your SDK from the following command:

flutter upgrade --force

OR

flutter upgrade

after upgrading SDK run flutter pub get

I hope this will fix your problem, Happy Fluttering.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59788677/16252358] you should follow this link hope you get your answers and maybe you are probably using another directory to perform flutter pub get, check your directory path

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday another package. I solved downgrade package version of troubled package. So you can try downgrade active_ecommerce_flutter

Comment: it is not working T_T it shows another error

Comment: here it is : There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".