# Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build

I was trying to realease the apk of my flutter application.
I ran the,"Flutter Build apk" Command and it poped out this error.

PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Weather App> flutter build apk
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

Comment: Confirm whether Weather App is the root directory of your project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix "No pubspec.yaml file found" in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786432/how-do-i-fix-no-pubspec-yaml-file-found-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

**Go to your correct project path then run below command**

C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Weather App> // your command

then run the following

for clean the project:

```
flutter clean
```

for run the project:

```
flutter run
```

for create `APK` file of the project:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

Make sure you're in the root directory. (The folder where the lib, android, etc folders are). If you're using a code editor like Vs Code, check if the terminal is in that folder. If not, cd into it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in root directory of Weather App and also the `pubspec.yaml` file is there (So it is not deleted mistakenly by you).
Do `flutter clean`
then `flutter pub get` then build apk