# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/rioland/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.0"

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, sharedpreferences

this is the error am getting when ever i run pub.yaml
i thing the error is coming from sharepreference

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/rioland/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.0".
#0      new Pubspec.load (package:pub/src/pubspec.dart:224:7)
#1      new Package.load (package:pub/src/package.dart:131:29)
#2      Entrypoint._createPackageGraph (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:180:36)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Entrypoint.resolveExecutable (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:556:8)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      getExecutableForCommand (package:pub/src/executable.dart:350:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      RunCommand.run (package:dartdev/src/commands/run.dart:324:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      DartdevRunner.runCommand (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:240:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      runDartdev (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:59:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      main (file:///Volumes/Work/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart:11:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217278/could-not-find-a-file-named-pubspec-yaml-in)

Comment: What do you mean by running `pub.yaml`?

Comment: Why is this tagged `WINAPI`?